# RouterConfiguration and Router undefined in aurelia

Tags: import, routes, aurelia, routeconfig

I am very new to Aurelia and just trying to apply navigation to my    project.Though i import aurelia-router still it says RouterConfiguration and Router are undefined in constructor

```js
import {Todo} from './ToDo/todo';
import {RouterConfiguration, Router} from 'aurelia-router';


export class App {
    heading = "Todos";
    todos: Todo[] = [];
    todoDescription = '';
    router :any;
    list: any[];

    constructor(RouterConfiguration: RouterConfiguration, Router: Router) {

        this.todos = [];
        this.configureRouter(RouterConfiguration, Router);
        //console.log("klist", this.list);
    }

    //config.map() adds route(s) to the router. Although only route, name, 
    //moduleId, href and nav are shown above there are other properties that can be included in a route.
    //The class name for each route is 
    configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router): void {
        this.router = router;
        config.title = 'Aurelia';
        config.map([
            { route: '', name: 'home', moduleId: 'home/home', nav: true, title: 'Home' },
            { route: 'users', name: 'users', moduleId: './Friends/Friends', nav: true },
            //{ route: 'users/:id/detail', name: 'userDetail', moduleId: 'users/detail' },
            //{ route: 'files/*path', name: 'files', moduleId: 'files/index', href: '#files', nav: 0 }
        ]);
    }

    addTodo() {
        if (this.todoDescription) {
            this.todos.push(new Todo(this.todoDescription));
           // this.todoDescription = '';
        }
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By convention, Aurelia looks in the initial class that loads (App) for the **configureRouter()** function and executes it. This means, you do not have to inject anything in the constructor.

It looks like you've simply added too much. I think fixing your sample seems to be as easy as removing some stuff, like so:

```js
import { Todo } from './ToDo/todo';
import { RouterConfiguration, Router } from 'aurelia-router';

export class App {
    heading = "Todos";
    todos: Todo[] = [];
    todoDescription = '';
    list: any[];

    constructor() {
      // note: removed routing here entirely (you don't need it)
      // also, you've already declared this.todos above, so no need to do it here again
    }

    configureRouter(config : RouterConfiguration, router : Router): void {
        this.router = router;
        config.title = 'Aurelia';
        config.map([
            { route: '', name: 'home', moduleId: 'home/home', nav: true, title: 'Home' },
            { route: 'users', name: 'users', moduleId: './Friends/Friends', nav: true }
        ]);
    }

    addTodo() {
      // removed this for brevity
    }

 }
```

This should resolve your 'undefined' errors on Router and RouteConfiguration. As an additional note, don't forget to add the `<router-view>` to your html template as well. Otherwise, you'll get no errors but the views won't show up either:

```
 <template>
    <div class="content">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
 </template>
```

Great documentation on this can be found at the [Aurelia Docs - Routing](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/1).

Comment: Thanks @ashley , it helped

Comment: @ashley is it have to add to all the templates or adding to app.html will do it?